# Mozilla "Jetpack" Add-On: Anchor Panel to Widget

Tags: firefox-addon, widget, panel, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm making a Jetpack extension in which a widget opens a panel.  Clicking the widget opens the panel as expected (anchored in the lower-right corner to the widget).  But if I call widget.panel.show() from my code, the panel opens detached from the widget, centered in the screen, floating in space.

In short, how can I fix this?

1. Can I simulate a click event on the widget (somehow) instead of calling widget.panel.show()?
2. Can I force the panel to anchor to the widget?

This question has a solution that worked in the previous Jetpack API, but I can't translate to the new interface:
[Using positioning 'Panel' in new Jetpack API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908931/using-positioning-panel-in-new-jetpack-api)

Answer (score 3):

```
panel.show(require("tab-browser").activeTab.ownerDocument.getElementById('widget:yourAddonId@package.json-yourWidgetId'));
```

Works for me with Addon SDK 1.8.1
Where:
yourAddonId@package.json - your addon id from package.json
yourWidgetId - your widget id

Comment: Been looking for a solution to this for a long time. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

```
panel.show(widget)
```

isn't working?

Comment: No -- this turns out to be a documented bug in the alpha3 jetpack release.