# How can i anchor a panel to a widget (Firefox Addon-SDK)

Tags: firefox, widget, panel, firefox-addon-sdk, add-on

Helo, i try to develop a (my first) firefox add-on. It should show a panel at several defined url with some content. This works if i click on widget-symbol fine. Now i want, that the panel is displayed if the user loads the page.

panel.show(); displays the panel centered. I would like to map/anchor the panel to the widget, so that the panel ist displayed in the rigth bottom corner.

The solutions https://gist.github.com/azu/4413137 and [Mozilla "Jetpack" Add-On: Anchor Panel to Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478434/mozilla-jetpack-add-on-anchor-panel-to-widget) did'nt work for me. (SDK 1.13.2 with Add-On Builder)

**My code:**

```
thePanel = panel.Panel({
    width: 320,
    height: 170,
    contentScriptFile: [self.data.url('jquery.js'), self.data.url('panel.js')],
    contentScriptWhen: "ready",
    contentScript: "SOMESCRIPT",
    contentURL: self.data.url('thecontent.html'),
    onMessage: function (item) {
      console.log('message : "' + item + '"');
      tabs.open(item);   
    }
});


var widget = widgets.Widget({
    id: "my-id",
    label: ".de",
    panel: thePanel,
    contentURL: self.data.url("favicon.ico"),
    onClick: function() {
        /*blabla*/
    }
});

tabs.on('ready', function(tab) {
  check_content(); // loads thecontent.html for panel content
  thePanel.show(); // Shows panel at center
});
```

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

```
thePanel = panel.Panel({
    width: 320,
    height: 170,
    contentScriptFile: [self.data.url('jquery.js'), self.data.url('panel.js')],
    contentScriptWhen: "ready",
    contentScript: "SOMESCRIPT",
    contentURL: self.data.url('thecontent.html'),
    onMessage: function (item) {
      console.log('message : "' + item + '"');
      tabs.open(item);   
    }
});


var widget = widgets.Widget({
    id: "my-id",
    label: ".de",
    //panel: thePanel,
    contentURL: self.data.url("favicon.ico"),
    onClick: function(view) {
        /*This will work*/
       view.panel = thePanel;
       /*This will work*/
    }
});

Instead of using panel.show(), use view.panel = thePanel;
```